# CSS background image that can scroll

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I am trying to create a background image that will have a scroll bar to scroll the image down vertically.  I like the idea of using width and height percentages because it seems like this method always fits the image to any screen resolution.  Unfortunately, the length of the image is rather large and therefore the bottom of the image gets cut off.  I have tried various ways to get this working including changing the background-size properties, using overflow-y:scroll and other edits that are not worth mentioning.  Here is the code I am working on thus far:

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
<div class='image'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
body { 
    margin:0;
}
.image {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    background:black;
    background-image:url(../pictures/testjpg);
    background-size:cover;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Is the div currently the full height of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** without height you can't scroll the image top to bottom. but you cant fit this any screen.

```css
body,html {

  margin: 0;
   
}

.image {
  background-image: url("http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_parallax.jpg");
  background-position:center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  
  height:300vh;
  
  }
```

```html
<body>

   <div class="image">

 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The scroll bar does not seem to be actually scrolling the content.

Comment: so you want the image to be scrolling ?? then you need to set a minimum height for image class. Or you want to make parallax scrolling effect ?

Comment: I would like the image to scroll so that when you are scrolled up to the top of the image, you see the top of the image.  And when you scroll to the bottom of the image, you see the bottom of the image.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: This scrolls the image, but the issue is that the width does not fit the screen.  Setting a fixed width fixes the issue for one screen resolution, but will be off for any other resolutions.

Comment: @user6636427 check again with any device

Comment: Yes! that's absolutely it! Thank you so much Mostafa!!

Answer (score 0):

A scroll bar moves the viewport so that you can see what's not on the screen.  At the above code, if you make your image to expand&contract by giving it relative height (%100 height&width of the screen), there will never be a 'scroll-able' vertical scroll bar because there's nothing to scroll to. It never 'overflows'.

To actually have scroll-able images, you need to give it a width - or in this case- height larger than your viewport.

Comment: Giving the div a specific width and height will allow for scroll, but when viewing the page on a screen with a different resolution, the width of the image will be off.  Is there a way to set these properties and have the image "rescale" to fit the resolution of a different screen?